# How to change DrawerNavigator content react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have both `DrawerNavigator` and `StackNavigator` in my app. There are two users `members` and `limited` users.

So when `limited` user logged in I want to remove `MyProfile` from `DrawerNavigator` and when `member` logged in `MyProfile` should show. How to achieve this. Please have a look into my code.

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Splash: { screen: Splash },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Home: { screen: Home },
    About: { screen: About },
    ListEvents: { screen: ListEvents }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Splash',
    headerMode: 'none'
}
);

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: AppNavigator,
    MyProfile: { screen: MyProfile },
    About: { screen: About }
});

const MainNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
    HomeDrawer: DrawerNavigator,
    AuthStack: AppNavigator
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigation);

export default AppContainer;
```

How to achieve my result in the above code? I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

**Suppose you have a boolean limited , then you can pass to a function to get AppContainer according to condition**

```
export default function AppContainer(limited) {
  const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Splash: { screen: Splash },
      Login: { screen: Login },
      Home: { screen: Home },
      About: { screen: About },
      ListEvents: { screen: ListEvents }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Splash",
      headerMode: "none"
    }
  );

  const DrawerNavigator = limited
    ? createDrawerNavigator({
        Home: AppNavigator,
        About: { screen: About }
      })
    : createDrawerNavigator({
        Home: AppNavigator,
        MyProfile: { screen: MyProfile },
        About: { screen: About }
      });

  const MainNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
    HomeDrawer: DrawerNavigator,
    AuthStack: AppNavigator
  });

  return createAppContainer(MainNavigation);
}
```

**Then use it in your AppRegistry component**

```
import React from "react";
import AppContainer from "./AppContainer";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const limited = true; // set true or false
    const Navigation = AppContainer(limited);
    return <Navigation />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Error shown `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor NavigationContainer cannot be invoked without 'new'`